# Questions about combining Hystrix with Feign

Tags: spring-cloud

I am trying to use the new HystrixFeign support in Feign. Here is what my code looks like

```
route66Client =
            HystrixFeign.builder()
                .logger(new Slf4jLogger())
                .encoder(new GsonEncoder())
                .target(Route66Client.class, "http://route66/");
```

The Route66Client is defined as

```
public interface Route66Client {
    @RequestLine("POST /route")
    ApiResponse getRoute(
        RouteRequest request);
}
```

When i try to run the code. I get UnknownHostException. As it is not able to resolve route66 for its hostname. Anyone knows what i could be missing ?

Further i had this working with regular Feign ( not HystrixFeign ). All i did was to annotate my Route66Client class with @FeignClient("...") and then injecting Route66Client in the calling class ( So no Feign.builder() was used )

But i couldn't find some @HystrixFeignClient annotation. So i went ahead and started using the HystrixFeign.builder(). But then when i did that the serviceName->Address resolution stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the benefits of eureka, don't use the builder directly. Put `@EnableFeignClients` on an `@Configuration` class (usually your application). Then label `Route66Client` with `@FeignClient("route66")` and inject `Route66Client`. This is only available in Brixton's 2nd Milestone.  See [the documentation](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#spring-cloud-feign).

Comment: I have EnableFeignClients annotation and doing exactly as you described. But i guess then i can't use HystrixFeign.builder

Comment: No, you can't. You need to `@Autowire Route66Client route66Client` in the classes that need the client. Otherwise, feign is not setup properly to use eureka.

Comment: Is it intended to be that way ? Or you plan to implement an annotation like @HystrixFeignClient ?

Comment: It's intended that way. It automatically enables Hystrix with feign.